# Index/match referring to concatenated cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to index/match a range with a concatenated date in a cell. The cell '10-year SGS'!F6 in the index/match formula below is a concatenated date.

The date formula is:

=CONCATENATE(E6,"/",C6,"/",A6).

The index/match formula is:

=INDEX('10-year US'!$B$12:$B$4427,MATCH('10-year SGS'!F6,'10-year US'!$A$12:$A$4427,0))

Strangely, if I type the date manually into the concatenated cell, then index/match works. The format for both cells is "date".

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string that looks like a date is not the same thing as a date. Try creating an actual date with the [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29).

```
=DATE(A6, E6, C6)
```

Alternately, you could wrap your [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-5B0392B2-94EF-49EA-8532-4FDD3A69D362) with the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-b5bd5892-0c18-4c78-be4a-d7b5b3525e23) to convert the string looking like a date to an actual date.

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(E6,"/",C6,"/",A6))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right, concatenate does not make sense here at all.

Answer (score 1):

If using the typed date works, then replace:

```
=CONCATENATE(E6,"/",C6,"/",A6)
```

with either:

```
=DATE(A6,E6,C6)
```

or

```
=DATE(A6,C6,E6)
```

depending on your regional date system